How to access SwiftUI Button instance at particular index in LazyVStack which the rootView of a UIHostingController?
I have a custom SwiftUI containerView which contains a set of SwiftUI buttons.
The SwiftUI button contains a UIKit UIView which I need to be used by the main UIViewConroller. The code looks something like as below:
    public struct ContainerView: View {
        public var body: some View {
           LazyVStack {
           ForEach(viewModel.buttonViewModels, id:\.self) { buttonViewModel in 
           CustomButton(buttonViewModel)
       }
     }
    }
   }

    public class CustomButton: View {
    public var backgroundUIView = BackgroundUIView()
    public var body: some View {
        Button(action: viewModel.tapEvent), label: {
           ZStack {
               backgroundUIView
               Text(viewModel.title)
           } 
        }
    }


    public BackgroundUIView: UIViewRepresentable {
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UIView {
        let view = UIView()
        view.backgroundColor = .blue
        return view
    }


    public CustomHostingController: UIHostingController<ContainerView> {
        public var containerViewModel: ContainerViewModel

        public init?(containerViewModel: ContainerViewModel) {
           self.containerVieModel = containerViewModel
           super.init(rootView: ContainerView())
        }
   }

In CustomHostingController how can I access CustomButton at particular index I want something like this.
extension CustomHostingController {
    func getButtonAtIndex(index: Int) -> CustomButton {
       rootView.body.subviews[index]
    }
}

I need to find the CustomButton instance at particular index in CustomHostingController.
Tried to find a way to find Swiftui button at particular index in ContainerView. like
    extension CustomHostingController {
        func getButtonAtIndex(index: Int) -> CustomButton {
           rootView.body.*subviews[index]*
        }
    }

In unlike UIKit in SwiftUI there is no way to do this  subViews[at index]. How can I access CustomButton instance at particular index?
I need access to CustomButton because CustomHostingController is a childViewController to a UIKit UIViewController, and I want to present a third party provided Popover controller (UIKit implementation) which requires the UIView as the source view for presenting it.  The third party popover controller initializer needs a UIView or UIButton as the parameter sourceView so that the arrow pointer of the Popover controller can point to the UIView or UIButton.
So I need to use the customButton instance like as below:
'[[ThirdPartyPopoverController alloc]  initWithDescription: @"Test coachmark presented" fromSourceView:customButton.backgroundUIView];`

You can’t SwiftUI Views are not meant to be accessed from the outside or from parents. Views don’t belong in properties.

You'll need to expose the UIView (in this case, the backgroundUIView) to your CustomHostingController. This can be done by passing a callback to the CustomButton, which lets the hosting controller know when a new UIView is created.
try this:
public struct BackgroundUIView: UIViewRepresentable {
    var onUIViewCreated: ((UIView) -> Void)?

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UIView {
        let view = UIView()
        view.backgroundColor = .blue
        onUIViewCreated?(view)
        return view
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIView, context: Context) {}
}

public struct CustomButton: View {
    public var viewModel: ButtonViewModel
    public var index: Int
    public var onUIViewCreated: ((Int, UIView) -> Void)?

    public var body: some View {
        Button(action: viewModel.tapEvent) {
            ZStack {
                BackgroundUIView(onUIViewCreated: { view in
                    onUIViewCreated?(index, view)
                })
                Text(viewModel.title)
            }
        }
    }
}

public struct ContainerView: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: ContainerViewModel
    var onUIViewCreated: ((Int, UIView) -> Void)?

    public var body: some View {
        LazyVStack {
            ForEach(viewModel.buttonViewModels.indices, id: \.self) { index in
                CustomButton(viewModel: viewModel.buttonViewModels[index],
                             index: index,
                             onUIViewCreated: onUIViewCreated)
            }
        }
    }
}

public class CustomHostingController: UIHostingController<ContainerView> {
    public var containerViewModel: ContainerViewModel
    private var buttonUIViews: [Int: UIView] = [:]

    public init(containerViewModel: ContainerViewModel) {
        self.containerViewModel = containerViewModel
        super.init(rootView: ContainerView(viewModel: containerViewModel, onUIViewCreated: { [weak self] index, uiView in
            self?.buttonUIViews[index] = uiView
        }))
    }

    @objc required dynamic init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    public func getButtonAtIndex(index: Int) -> UIView? {
        return buttonUIViews[index]
    }
}

and use like below:
let hostingController = CustomHostingController(containerViewModel: yourViewModel)
if let buttonView = hostingController.getButtonAtIndex(index: 2) {
    let popover = ThirdPartyPopoverController(description: "Test", fromSourceView: buttonView)
    // Present your popover
}

